# Iterate a function on each div with id containing specific word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each, gsap

I have two div's (they just look like blocks, with a background-color, width, and height values assigned in CSS). I would like to write one function that selects all div's with an id that contains a specific word, in this case "image". My div's are written as:

```
<div id="image1"> </div>
<div id="image2"> </div>
```

I want the function to only execute on each div when it is clicked on. I have something close to what I want. It will work properly when clicking on the first div, however after clicking the second div, it will execute the code on both div's. My code is a simply GSAP timeline.

```
window.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
  if(e.target.id.includes("image")){
    var target = e.target;
    tl.to(target, .6, {x: ($(".container").width()/2) + (target.style.width/2), y:($(".container").height()/2) * -1 + (target.style.height/2)}, 0);
    tl.reversed() ? tl.play() : tl.reverse();
  }
})
```

my GSAP timeline is declared above the function as -

```
var tl = new TimelineMax({paused:true, reversed:true});
```

This is almost working, however I don't know how to change it so that it will only execute the function on the div that is clicked on. I've tried changing the e.target to e.currentTarget and $(e.target), but I'm pretty new to code and I don't really understand how all these things work.

Another function I've tried which is not working at all (says div is undefined) is this -

```
$(div[id*="image"]).each(function(){
  $(this).on("click", function(){
  var target = $(this);
  tl.to(target, .6, {x: ($(".container").width()/2) + (target.style.width/2), y:($(".container").height()/2) * -1 + (target.style.height/2)}, 0);
  tl.reversed() ? tl.play() : tl.reverse();
  })
})
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: on your last code block change `$(div[id*="image"])` to `$("div[id*=\"image\"]")`, note the extra quotes

Comment: use `$(this)`..

Comment: With $("div[id*=\"image\"]") I still receive console.log error that 'div' is undefined?